# IText: how to draw image over a line (both on a PdfTemplate)

Tags: itext

I have defined a chart-panel-template, which owns a graph-template and other stuff. 
The graph-template shows both x-y-axis and also the measurement points. At the end I wrapp this chartpanel-template in an image object, and then add it to document object. 
Problem is: I want to connect the measurement point setting a dot-image on each point. I am unable to put the dot-image on the connecting lines. Lines go through the dots. This is a part of my code:

```
while(iter.hasNext()){
            key= iter.next();
            value= (int) this.getDataset().get(key);
            y= (int)(value * this.getyConversionRatio() + getXAxisHeight());
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(this.templateContent, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,new Paragraph(String.valueOf(value), this.font), x, y+ getDotIamge().getHeight()*2, 0);     

            if(i==0){
                this.templateContent.moveTo(x + getDotIamge().getWidth()/2, y + getDotIamge().getHeight()/2);
            }else{
                this.templateContent.lineTo(x + getDotIamge().getWidth()/2, y + getDotIamge().getHeight()/2);                   
            } 

            //this.templateContent.stroke();  // this call doesn't draw any lines at all.

            getDotIamge().setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
            this.templateContent.addImage(getDotIamge());

            i++;
            x= x+ this.getxScaleStepLength();           
        }

      //this.templateContent.stroke();  // this call draw the lines as expected over the dots.
```

I want the dots to be drawn over the lines. What shall I take into consideration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide more info. For instance: I see `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` operators, but I don't see a `stroke()` anywhere. Maybe that's the problem: you should draw the lines *before* stroking the path.

Comment: I call stroke() after the while-loop. If I call it directly after lineto, the lines are not drawn at all.

Comment: OK, that explains your problem, doesn't it? You *first* draw the image dots. *After* those dots are drawn, you stroke the path you've created. Hence the lines cover the images. If you want the images to cover the lines, you have to stroke the lines *first*, and *then* draw the images. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: As I mentioned: if I call stroke() directly after the lineTo() , no lines are drawn at all. I dont know whether it is because of beeing in a while-loop? Maybe I have to write 2 loops? No, I tried it with 2 loops, but dots remain up the lines

Comment: I don't see you use `saveState()`/`restoreState()` anywhere. I don't see you define the line width. You are mixing the creation of a path with `Do` operators to add images. Creating two loops would probably make things more clean and less error-prone.

Comment: If you add a `stroke()` method after each `lineTo()`, it is only logical that only the first line is drawn and that the rest are omitted.

Comment: Ow, I see that you adapted your question. Putting `stroke()` at that place doesn't make any sense at all. It's normal that nothing is drawn. You always need one `moveTo()`, one or more `lineTo()` and one `stroke()` operation. In your case, you had a sequence of `moveTo()`/`stroke()`, followed by several `lineTo()`/`stroke()` operations. That goes against all logic, doesn't it?

Comment: OK; I got the logic. There is no solution but using 2 loops. First to draw the lines conecting the measurement-points. A second loop to draw the dot-point. it is not really nice in the code to have exactly the same loop twice. But it shows the graph as is desired.

Comment: You could use one loop and create two `PdfTemplate` objects that you then add one over the other.